# playing sound on AX 09

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I would know if is possible to play a sound on AX 2009. With a fast search on internet I found a WInAPI function that allows me to play a sound (sndPlaySound()), but this function works on AX 4.0, not on AX 2009 because this function not exists on AX 2009.

How I can play a sound? Is there a new function?

Comment: What i did is included the method sndPlaySound() into WinAPI class in AX 2009. It works fine. Just want to know if this is the appropriate way. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Could you  please tell me if I can play only *.WAV file? can others be played in AX??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that `sndPlaySound` was removed either for security reasons or because it was not used in standard AX.

Also WinAPI [sndPlaySound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713269%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is kind of depricated, the more advanced and newer function is [PlaySound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712879%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

As you already have done, you can recreate the function, which is the thing to do if your application needs it.

Comment: Yea sndPlaySound  is working great. Well thanks a lot for the information. I looked for PlaySound in AX 2009 but couldnt find it, just want to have a look at it. Where can I find it?

Comment: It is in WinAPI (i.e. Windows), but it is not implemented in AX.

Comment: Could you  please tell me if I can play only *.WAV file? can others be played in AX??

Comment: From the Windows documentation: "The parameter can be either an entry in the registry or in WIN.INI that identifies a system sound, or it can be the name of a waveform-audio file."

Remember, AX does not play any sounds, it uses a system call to do the job. If it is not up to the job, use another player as Jay suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the .NET [SoundPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143766.aspx) class:

```
static void Job1(Args _args)
{
    System.Media.SoundPlayer SoundPlayer=new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\WINDOWS\MEDIA\DING.WAV");
    ;
    SoundPlayer.Play();
}
```

Comment: Could you  please tell me if I can play only *.WAV file? can others be played in AX??